# Sharepoint Online display Angular Snippet

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, angular2

I'm pretty new to Sharepoint and want to create some kind of dynamic Styleguide. Therefore I need to display some small Angular Snippets with additional libraries like Bootstrap.

Is there a way how to display a working Angular snippet in SharePoint Online? The snippets are components line buttons, datepicker or textfields that should work / be clickable.

I'm using SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to display angular snippet is a content editor webpart. Maybe you can create a page in SharePoint designer surface your angular app there through a content editor webpart.

The better way is to use a SharePoint hosted app that leverages Angular to achieve your functionality.

I would recommend you to go through this [very good tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs) by Atish Dipongkar around using angular in SharePoint.

Also, Andrew Connell's guide to creating [SharePoint hosted angular Single Page Apps](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Learning-Path-Manager-Code-Sample), is a great resource.